# Error using pyUniversalLibrary on 64bit python

Tags: python

pyUniversalLibrary is a python library for communicating with measurement computing DIO cards.
I installed pyUniversalLibrary version 20061020 and tried running a program that uses it but I got the following error:

"WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

I think this is because I'm running a 64bit version of python 2.7.

I remember that one of my coworkers solved this problem by changing one line of code in the library itself. But I don't remember how he did it and he's out on vacation.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `cbw = ctypes.windll.cbw64` instead of `cbw = ctypes.windll.cbw32` in `UniversalLibrary.py`.

Comment: This seems to work! Good intuition, and thanks for your help